# How to reach a GET parameter in configuration of form?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm in the middle of `configure()` method and I must set a default selected value for a combobox. The value is in the URL, but no request or any object.

How to reach this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Not a good idea to use `sfContext` in that context.](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/)

Better send the parameter in the constructor of the form.
Something like this:

```
$form = new Form(array(), array(‘my_form_param’ => $request->getParameter('my_get_param'));
```

In the form you can call it with:

```
$this->getOption('my_form_param')
```

Comment: better, but the constructor uses more parameter in symfony's core. What if the inner behaviour changes someday?

Comment: The current constructor for `sfFormPropel` class, for example,  is  `__construct($object = null, $options = array(), $CSRFSecret = null)`. You will need to use the `options` array to send your param. I'm not sure what you mean by "inner behaviour changes". Changes in the form constructor? That's highly unlikely. The development for sf1x has stopped. The current version under development is sf2x

Comment: I see. This article shows about the same http://eatmymonkeydust.com/2009/08/symfony-forms-flexible-widgets-based-on-user-credentials/ yea I meant what if Fabien changes that constructor. But OK, im fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request from anywhere like this:

`sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParameter('foo')`

Comment: Not a good idea to use `sfContext` in that context: http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/

Comment: @VladJula-Nedelcu I agree passing in a config parameter to the form would be better, and that sfContext sucks, but the issue with sfContext not existing will only occur in a task (I think?), so should be OK here.